# Flask - Reset everything when user leaves

Tags: python, session, heroku, flask

I'm writing an Flask app for learning purpose, I don't use flask session as it somehow didn't work. Supposed that I have a list that is empty at the beginning. When user connect to the link webapp.herokuapp.com the following index is executed:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True 
app.secret_key = 'nosecret'

random_number_list = []

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    # Read from the from input
    usrn = request.form['username']
    pswd = request.form['password']
    random_number_list = randList() # The list will have 10-20 random integer elements
```

The code works perfectly when I print out the random_number_list on the website. However, when I visit my app again at webapp.herokuapp.com, the random_number_list is not reset. Instead, new elements are added to the last list and the process keeps going.

```
E.g: at first connection to the webapp:
1 4 5 6 7
Second connection:
1 4 5 6 7 2 3 4 2 1
```

in the def login() i try to have random_number_list = [] before generating new result, but the list is not reset either, it is just reset whenever I push new codes to heroku.

Can anyone help me with some ideas to solve this problem? Thank you so much

Comment: How is your `randList()` implemented?

Comment: its: return [random.randint(0,9) for r in xrange(10)]

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your `random_number_list` array is a global variable -- it will stay the same (in memory) until your dyno restarts.

Since you're visiting the site multiple times, the data will keep growing.

What is your goal here? To have a user log in-- store some user-specific stuff -- then log out? If that's the case, you really need to be using sessions. The flask session framework (http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#sessions) allows you to store data on the client's computer -- this way, each time a user returns to your site you can retrieve whatever data you had previously stored on that user's computer.

Be careful, however -- there are many security implications for doing things this way.